# Import two JSON files into two columns of the same collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using Python with MongoDB but instead of using PyMongo for importing the JSON files, have opted for using sub-process because that seems to be the recommended way when dealing with larger files.

I have two relatively large JSON files (>10MB). I need to import these two files into the same collection as two different columns. The way things are set up now, I am using something along the lines of:

`mongoimport -u user -p pass --jsonArray --db db --collection col --file json.json`

Obviously, this is only good for one file. Merging the datasets is not an option as that seems to take forever. How should  I approach this?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to explore the `--mode=merge|upsert` and `--upsertFields` options in the [mongoimport documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/).

Wihout more specifics from yourself, it's unlikely you will get a more specific answer.